# Google API with python error when trying to refresh token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, python-3.8, google-api-python-client

So I'm trying to write this program in python 3.8.5 which interacts with Google spreadsheets, but when the token expires, I don't know how to refresh it.

My code is pretty much copied from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

def service_spread():
    """
    Creates token for spreadsheet with required authorisation.
    Returns required service.
    """
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token_spread.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token_spread.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token_spread.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    return build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

If there is no token, it works like a charm. In case there is a token and it is expired, it raises the following error:

```
RefreshError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-63b097a471a1> in <module>
----> 1 service = service_spread()

<ipython-input-5-12e029dbbb2f> in service_spread()
     14     if not creds or not creds.valid:
     15         if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
---> 16             creds.refresh(Request())
     17         else:
     18             flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py in refresh(self, request)
    206         scopes = self._scopes if self._scopes is not None else self._default_scopes
    207 
--> 208         access_token, refresh_token, expiry, grant_response = _client.refresh_grant(
    209             request,
    210             self._token_uri,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py in refresh_grant(request, token_uri, refresh_token, client_id, client_secret, scopes)
    246         body["scope"] = " ".join(scopes)
    247 
--> 248     response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
    249 
    250     try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py in _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
    122                 retry += 1
    123                 continue
--> 124             _handle_error_response(response_body)
    125 
    126     return response_data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py in _handle_error_response(response_body)
     58         error_details = response_body
     59 
---> 60     raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
     61 
     62 

RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Bad Request', '{\n  "error": "invalid_scope",\n  "error_description": "Bad Request"\n}')
```

I have searched all over the internet but I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone help me? I need this code to be running unsupervised, so I would need for the token to be automatically refreshed, without any human intervention.

Comment: Did you change the SCOPES? if so delete token_spread.json and try and rerun it

Comment: No, I didn't change the SCOPES :(

Comment: Delete the token_spread.json and try and run it again.

Comment: I can do that now manually, but I need this code to be running unsupervised, so deleting the token_spread.json and creating it again every time doing all the authorisation process is not an option

Comment: Im not saying every time. I am just asking you to do it now to ensure that its not been corrupted for some reason.   What type of credentials did you create on Google developer console by the way?   Make sure you created installed credentials.

Comment: Ok I just deleted the token. The credentials I created are Desktop app credentials. Do you mean this could be the thing which is causing me this trouble? Thanks a lot for your help, btw.

Comment: When you run it again does it work?

Comment: Yes, it just created the token.

Comment: OK i have no idea why it didnt work before your error message is really weird as that is a valid scope, and its not the error message i would expect if you had not  given the correct scope.  Keep an eye on it and see if it happens again.  But if its going to be run unsupervised why not use a service account.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will definetely keep an eye on it and see if it happens again.

Comment: Has it happened again? Have you checked on using a service account to run it?

Comment: It hasn't happened again, I guess the token might have been corrupted or something.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this and I had the same problem and fixed it. There must be something wrong with their logic for checking if the token is expired. But I added a manual check to do it. In the `token.json` there's an `expiry` field which shows at which time the token will expire. I just manually checked if the current time is past that time or not. If so, I remove the file myself. My authentication code is below.

```
    def auth(self):
        creds = None
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
        if os.path.exists("token.json"):
            token = json.load(open("token.json"))
            expiry = datetime.fromisoformat(token["expiry"])
            if expiry < datetime.now(expiry.tzinfo):
                self.logger.info(
                    "Token expired, removing token.json and re-authenticating"
                )
                os.remove("token.json")
                creds = None
            else:
                self.logger.info("Reading credentials from existing token.json")
                creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                self.logger.info("Credentials expired, sending refresh request")
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                self.logger.info(
                    "Credentials not found, sending auth request to local server"
                )
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "credentials.json", SCOPES
                )
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open("token.json", "w") as token:
                self.logger.info("Saving credentials to token.json")
                token.write(creds.to_json())
        self.service = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=creds)
        self.logger.info("Completed Gmail authentication flow")
```